# How to rotate fixed object using PhysicsJS?

Tags: javascript, gravity, physics-engine, physicsjs

I'm learning new javascript lib PhysicsJS ([link](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/)).

If anybody can help me or show me example of:

How to rotate fixed object (like propeller and balls bounce of it)?

How to set in world some object that bounce with object that not bounce?

Edge-collision-detection (AABB) , Is it possible to do a circle instead of the cube?

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate objects by changing angular property
like this:

```js
world.on('step', function(){
  barrel.state.angular.pos += 0.02;
  world.render();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question about rotating a "fixed" object was asked in another post: [PhysicsJS - how to create a body which rotates about a fixed point when struck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066434/physicsjs-how-to-create-a-body-which-rotates-about-a-fixed-point-when-struck)

As for setting some objects that bounce and some that don't: This can't be done yet. It's being worked out as part of future development: https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS/issues/30

For edge collision detection, right now it's only possible to use rectangles. You would have to modify the edge collision detection code to make it a circle.

Comment: Example for fixed object is good but as I wrote, it is necessary to work as a propeller. Propeller should push the ball.